# Salesforce - Dev Hub

Tags: salesforcedx

I wanted to setup Scratch Orgs in my test Sandbox. I see that Dev Hub is not available (I cant see it in Setup) for my full copied Sandbox. I can however see it in my Production environment.

I prefer to have connections running to my Test Environment only so that we dont accidentally deploy something.

If I turn on Dev Hub in Production does that mean my Sandboxes get it or can I only use Scratch orgs in production? I dont see anything in Salesforces documentation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable Dev Hub in Production (or Business Org). Enabling that lets you to create Scratch Orgs. You [cannot turn on Dev Hub in any Sandboxes other than Production](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/environment_hub_faq_sandbox.htm).

You don't *use Scratch Orgs in Production* but use the Dev Hub to create Scratch Orgs. The below documentation links provides more information on this:

- [Enable Dev Hub in Your Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/environment_hub_faq_sandbox.htm)
- [Can I enable the Environment Hub in a sandbox org?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/environment_hub_faq_sandbox.htm)